# How many ways to arrange the numbers $1...n$ such that..

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $\{1...n\}$ and $k$, a number between $1\le k \le n$.
>   How many permutations are there for the set, where $k$ is smaller than all the number to it's right.

**My thought:**
We have to place $k$ at the cell number $k$.
Then, we have $(k-1)!$ permutations for the smaller numbers and $(n-k)!$ for the greater numbers. All in all, we have: $(k-1)!(n-k)!$

Somehow, the right answer is:
$$\left( {\matrix{
   n  \cr 
   k  \cr 
 } } \right)(k - 1)!(n - k)!$$

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given the correct answer to the following question: how many permutations are there in which $k$ is smaller than all the numbers to its right *and larger than all the numbers to its left*.  However the last part was not specified in the question you asked.  For example if $n=7$ and $k=3$ then
$$(2,7,1,4,3,5,6)$$
is an allowable permutation, but you will not have counted it.

**Hint**.  First determine which places $k$ can occupy.  If $j$ is such a place then

- there are $n-k$ numbers larger than $k$, and you have to choose $n-j$ of them, in a particular order, to occupy the places to the right of $k$;
- There are now $j-1$ numbers which have to be placed in a particular order to the left of $k$.

So the answer will be
$$\sum_{j=?}^{?} (?)(?)$$
- see if you can fill in what is missing.

**On second thoughts** here is another argument which leads directly to the answer you were given.

- Choose (without regard to order) the places to be occupied by the numbers $1,\ldots,k$.
- Choose the order for these numbers, remembering that $k$ must be last.
- Order the remaining $n-k$ numbers into the remaining $n-k$ places.

**Best of all**: the answer you were given simplifies to
$$\frac{n!}{k}\ .$$
Here is an argument which gives this result immediately.  There are $n!$ permutations of the numbers altogether, and we determine the proportion of them which satisfy your conditions.  As in my second solution, the only thing that matters is that $k$ should be the last of the numbers $1,\ldots,k$ to appear in the permutation: as long as this is true, the locations of the larger numbers don't matter.  Among all orderings of the numbers $1,\ldots,k$, the number $k$ occurs with equal frequency in each of the $k$ places; so the proportion in which it occurs last is $1/k$, and the number of permutations of $1,\ldots,n$ in which this occurs is
$$\frac{n!}{k}$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We do not have to place $k$ in the $k$-th cell. We can place it in any of the cells that are in the $k$-th position **or later**.

Answer (score 1):

take the original combination with k at kth position ..call it initial position
number of ways = (k−1)!(n−k)!
now remove one from right of of k in initial position and put to left of k and arrange them 
number of ways = (k)!(n−k-1)! (n-k,1)
now remove 2 from right of k in initial position and put to the left of k and arrange them
number of ways = (k+1)!(n−k-2)! (n-k,2)
.
.
.
.
overall number of ways = ∑(from r=0 to r= n-k) {(n-k,r)(n-k-r)!(k+r-1)!}
rearrange it and get overall number of ways = (k-1)!(n-k)!∑(same limits) { (k-1+r,r)}